# Does Blazegraph support range query optimization?

Tags: sparql, triplestore, blazegraph

I am playing with Blazegraph. I insert some triples representing 'events', each of 'event' contains 3 triples and looks like this:

```
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/timestamp> '2020-01-02T03:04:05.000Z'^^xsd:dateTime .
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/a> %RANDOM_UUID% .
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/b> %RANDOM_UUID% .
```

Timestamps represent consecutive moments of time, each next event is 1 minute later than the previous one.

I made two sets of tests: once having 1 million events (so 3 million triples), and once having 3 million events (9 million triples).

I run queries like the following:

```
select ?event ?a ?v 
where {
  ?event <http://predicates/timestamp> ?timestamp .
  filter (?timestamp >= '2020-01-02T03:04:05.000Z'^^xsd:dateTime && ?timestamp < '2020-01-02T03:03:05.000Z'^^xsd:dateTime)
  ?event ?a ?v .
}
```

I started with queries returning 1000 events (3000 triples) and then went down to queries that only match 1 event (and return 3 triples) to make sure that result data set size does not influence the range query performance itself too much.

I also tried adding a hint found here https://sourceforge.net/p/bigdata/discussion/676946/thread/2cf9a1e8/?limit=25 to tell Blazegraph that it should use range query optimization by adding the following

```
hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
```

Right after the `filter` clause.

Also, it was mentioned that for some types range queries do not work while working for others (for ints they worked for johpfe), so I also tried to do another set of tests where timestamps are represented as ints (Unix timestamps):

```
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/timestamp> 1606528746 .
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/a> %RANDOM_UUID% .
<%event-iri%> <http://predicates/b> %RANDOM_UUID% .
```

The final query I tried was

```
select ?event ?a ?v 
where {
  ?event <http://predicates/timestamp> ?timestamp .
  filter (?timestamp >= 1606528746 && ?timestamp < 1606528806)
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
  ?event ?a ?v .
}
```

Whatever I try, I get the following results: for the smaller dataset (1 million timestamps/ints) queries take 1 second, sometimes more, but not less; for the bigger dataset (3 million timestamps/ints) queries take at least 3 seconds.

The difference is 3x, which perfectly correlates with 3x change of data volume. So it looks like the range optimization is not working.

I also compared against MongoDB. Having an index on 'timestamp' field, it always executes an analogous query in 30-50ms, no matter on what data size.

What do I do wrong? Is there a way to make Blazegraph apply the optimization here?

PS. I also tried putting the hint right after a **triple pattern**, not `filter` statement, as per https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/QueryHints which says the following about `rangeSafe` hint:

> Declare that the data touched by the query for a specific **triple pattern** is strongly typed, thus allowing a range filter to be pushed down onto an index.

So the query became

```
select ?event ?a ?v 
where {
  ?event <http://predicates/timestamp> ?timestamp .
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
  filter (?timestamp >= 1606528746 && ?timestamp < 1606528806)
  ?event ?a ?v .
}
```

But this query finds nothing, so the hint just breaks it.

Comment: Works for me on Wikidata: https://w.wiki/nxJ

Comment: Thank you @StanislavKralin, your example really helped to figure out what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the queries where the optimization does work.

This one is for the case of integers:

```
select ?event ?a ?v 
where {
  ?event <http://predicates/timestamp> ?timestamp .
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe "true" .
  filter (?timestamp >= "1606528746"^^xsd:int && ?timestamp < "1606528806"^^xsd:int)
  ?event ?a ?v .
}
```

And this one is for the case when timestamps are date-times:

```
select ?event ?a ?v 
where {
  ?event <http://predicates/timestamp> ?timestamp .
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true .
  filter (?timestamp >= '2021-11-07T22:08:24.022+04:00'^^xsd:dateTime && ?timestamp < '2021-11-07T22:10:24.022+04:00'^^xsd:dateTime)
  ?event ?a ?v .
}
```

What prevented the optimization from kicking in was:

1. For the case of integers, I did not specify literal type explicitly, so it was like `?timestamp >= 1606528746` instead of `?timestamp >= "1606528746"^^xsd:int`. Strangely enough, it breaks the optimization.
2. Also, the hint must be specified right after the triple pattern and NOT after the filter statement.

Also, it turned out that it is not important whether the hint contains `true` or `"true"`: both options work successfully.

Many thanks to @StanislavKralin for giving a working example using which I was able to transform my queries to a working form.

Comment: Hi Roman! Our GraphDB has a better literal index that indexes all kinds if numbers (eg `1606528746` means `"1606528746"^^xsd:integer`) and dates/dateTimes (in some scenarios not all dateTimes have the same resolution). And it doesn't need any hints

Comment: Thank you @VladimirAlexiev, I'll take a look